# Slide MKMapView specified number of pixels down or up

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

How would I slide MKMapView by given number of pixels vertically, I played it around a bit, here is my code, which offcourse does not work :(

```
var point = mapView.convert(mapView.centerCoordinate, toPointTo: self.view)

point.x += offSet.x
point.y += offSet.y

let center = mapView.convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: self.view)
mapView.setCenter(center, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out, here is the code, hope it will help someone ;)

```
func mapViewMoveBy(offset: CGPoint, animated: Bool = true) {
    var point = mapView.center

    point.x += offset.x
    point.y += offset.y

    let coordinate = mapView.convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
    mapView.setCenter(coordinate, animated: animated)
}
```

**Usage**

```
let slideFourtyPixelDown: CGFloat = -40
mapViewMoveBy(offset: CGPoint(x: 0, y: slideFourtyPixelDown))
```